# Return 10 rows with specific row in position 5 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to construct a leaderboard where I return 10 rows ordered by score.

However, I want a specific user (ME) to appear in row 5 - so I want the four scores above the specific user to be higher and the five users below the specific user to be lower scores.

There could be hundreds of rows in the database.

So, in other words, I'm trying to get 10 rows, with the user I want in the middle.

So something like this;

```
user_id, pos, name, score 
10, 1, Rita, 100 
50, 2, Sue, 95 
30, 3, Bob, 60 
90, 4, Billy, 50 
**14, 5, ME, 45** 
46, 6, Bob, 30 
89, 7, Thornton, 20 
83, 8, Jeremy, 10 
99, 9, Kyle, 5 
16, 10, John, 1
```

I think I could crack it with multiple SQL commands, but I'm absolutely stumped if it can be done in one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `pos` field is always up to date, you can use [the between operator](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php) after getting the position of `Me` in your database.
Using these two queries you can get your desired result:

```
select @pos:=pos FROM so where user_id=5;

select * 
FROM so
where pos between @pos-4 
              and @pos+5
order by score desc;
```

First query sets the `@pos` variable value to position of the row you want.
Second query fetches the result that are between `@pos-4 and @pos+5`.

Here's the output:

```
user_id pos name    score
3       3   Bob     130
4       4   Billy   120
6       5   Bob2    110
7       6   Joe     100
5       7   Me      90
8       8   Mario   80
9       9   Paul    70
10      10  Jeremy  60
11      11  Kyle    50
12      12  Kane    40
```

Here's the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f8H521NV23ucQzb72dKGaW/1).

You could also do it in a single query, but I think it'd hurt the performance.

```
select * 
FROM so
where pos between (select pos FROM so where user_id=5)-4 
              and (select pos FROM so where user_id=5)+5
order by score desc;
```